# Getting a BSOD after upgrading to MOSS SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, bsod

Recently we updated a SharePoint test server to MOSS SP2. After doing so, a series of errors appeared in the error log, along with a random blue screen of death. After the BSOD, the following screen appears:

[tried attaching but cannot because I'm new]

The error log entries vary pretty greatly. The most recent Event ID's are 10036, 7888 (quite a few), 7 & 63.

The 7888 error appears quiet a lot, and after doing some research it seems like a pretty common error. The error messages is "Invalid object name 'AR_CacheCounters'."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've upvoted your question but probably still won't give enough rep. Can you include a link to the image as it seems quite relevant. Also please tag any SharePoint questions with `sharepoint` as well as the product variant (e.g. `moss`) so it can be found by people following that tag. Thanks and welcome to Server Fault!

Comment: The image is http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/7050/bsodk.png. 

Just as a note, I did a Windows update, reading that the BSOD's error, "DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL", often comes from out of date Windows drivers, and when I returned today, the same BSOD was on the screen.

Will contiune to try "generic" BSOD remedees to this.

Comment: One more note, the machine is a VM, so the drivers are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note: It seems the cause of the issue was Daemon Tools. It was causing confusion with the VMTools and throwing a video driver related BSOD.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the source of your errors are but here's a place to start looking:

10036 Error: http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=10036&source=

7888 Error: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/63eaca58-7e89-4083-8411-5e92ec6eec30

**NOTE***-If this first link is right, check service enabled in your MOSS setup and make sure you don't have something enabled that you don't need for your particular license type

http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7888&eventno=8794&source=Office%20SharePoint%20Server&phase=1

7 Error (need more specifics as this is a generic error): http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=7&source=

**NOTE***-From first glance looks like error 7 might point to a bad drive. Is this vm local (workstation) or on ESX? Is it on a SAN or local disk space? Can you do storage migration and try this VM on another disk?

63 Error: http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=63&source=

**NOTE**- Again, hard to diagnose with no source information but looks like another possible issue with disk.

Comment: The VM is on ESX and attached to a SAN. All the other VM's in this cluster (hundreds) work perfectly fine, leading me to believe that this has more to do with the software update and less to do with the hardware. VMware infrastructure client does not contain any errors either. Also, the dump, as pictured above, did not appear in this most recent BSOD. Not sure why.

Thanks for your help so far though, I definitely appreciate any assistance I can get on this.